# How to properly move ownership in an inner loop in Rust?

Tags: rust, ownership

Question 1:
How to properly move ownership of the data, in an inner loop, so that once the final iteration gets done, the container iterated will be `Drop()`ed.

For example:

```
let left_strs: Vec<String> = Self::allowed(&slice[..i]);
let right_strs: Vec<String> = Self::allowed(&slice[i..]);
for left_str in left_strs{
    // how to properly move the ownership of the data here?
    for right_str in right_strs.iter(){
        ans.push(format!("({}, {})", left_str, right_str));
    }
}
```

Question 2:
For all the data in the vector, its ownership has been moved, and it has been `Drop()`ed eventually, will the vector(container) be automatically `Drop()`ed because of this?

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without a minimal working example showing your problem. Why do you need the container to be dropped at that point? What errors are you getting currently and why would moving be the solution?

Comment: well, you can not...it makes no sense, if you move ownership into the inner loop `right_strs` will be drop after the first iteration.

Comment: There's no particular reason to move ownership anyway, `format!()` doesn't consume the arguments it builds a new string.

Comment: Thanks for all the above replies, which I learned from.

Comment: @Emoun, thanks for your reply. I am a newbie, and just wildly exploring the possibilities now :).

Comment: @kmdreko, thanks :). I am trying my best to aggressively consume the resources, in order to save space, and minimize variable locality. The iteration itself moves the ownership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest thing that comes to my mind is to use a new scope:

```rust
fn main() {
    let left_strs: Vec<String> = vec!["one".to_string(), "two".to_string()];
    {
        let right_strs: Vec<String> = vec!["one".to_string(), "two".to_string()];
        // use a & on left_strs to avoid move
        for left_str in &left_strs {            
            for right_str in right_strs.iter() {
                println!("({}, {})", left_str, right_str);
            }
        }
    // right_strs is drop
    }
    // we can still use left_strs, since we used a & before
    for s in left_strs {
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}
```

This way, `right_strs` will be drop when the scope ends.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=245d8715cf4b70d638d29ed62e9f3811)

Comment: This hits the spot!